# Find all pairs of keys $(a, b)$ for affine ciphers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, cryptography

The question is as follows:

> Find all pairs of integer keys $(a, b)$ for affine ciphers for which
> the encryption function $c = (ap + b) \bmod 26$ is the same as the
> corresponding decryption function.

I'm trying to wrap my head around the answer provided:

> If $x$ is the inverse of $a$ modulo 26, then the decryption function for the encryption function $c = (ap+b) \bmod 26$ is $p = x(c − b) \bmod 26 = (xc − xb) \bmod 26$. Clearly two different pairs $(a, b)$ cannot give the same encryption function, so we need to solve the system of congruences $x \equiv a \pmod{26}$ and $b \equiv −xb \pmod{26}$. Only 1 and −1 (which is the same as 25) are their own multiplicative inverses modulo 26 (this can be verified by asking a computer algebra system to compute all the inverses), so there are two cases. If $a = 1$, then the second congruence becomes $b \equiv −b \pmod{26}$, whose solutions are $b = 0$ and $b = 13$. This says that the identity function $c = p \bmod 26$ satisfies the given condition (although that was obvious and not very interesting), and so does $c = (p + 13) \mod 26$. If $a = −1$, then the second congruence becomes $b \equiv b \pmod{26}$, which is satisfied by all values of $b$. Therefore all encryption functions of the form $c = (−p + b) \bmod 26$ also have themselves as the corresponding decryption function. The answer to the question phrased in terms of pairs is $(1, 0)$, $(1, 13)$, and $(−1, b)$ (or, equivalently, $(25, b)$) for all $b$.

How do we get the congruences $x \equiv a \pmod{26}$ and $b \equiv −xb \pmod{26}$ from $(xc − xb) \mod 26$?

Comment: Where do you see $a\equiv a$ and $b\equiv-ab$? I see $x\equiv a$ and $b\equiv-xb$, which is very different. Did you post this earlier, and then delete it? I know I've seen it earlier today.

Comment: @GerryMyerson My mistake. You are correct, I’m asking about x≡a and  b≡−xb. And nope, this is the first post I’ve made about this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $p\longmapsto ap+b\bmod{26}$ has inverse $c\longmapsto \frac{1}{a}(c-b)\bmod{26}$; this is always the case (provided $\gcd(a,26)=1$, which is clearly assumed).

Here we want the two functions to be the same. So denoting as the answer does, the multiplicative inverse modulo $26$ of $a$ by $x$, we have that we want
$$x(c-b) \equiv ac+b\pmod{26}$$
for all $c$.

This gives
$$\text{for all }c,\quad xc -xb \equiv ac+b\pmod{26}.$$
We can take $c=0$ and conclude that we must have $-xb\equiv b\pmod{26}$. And then cancelling we get $xc\equiv ac\pmod{26}$, and since this must hold for  all $c$, taking $c=1$ we get $x\equiv a\pmod{26}$.

So if the encryption function equals the decryption function, then we must have $b\equiv-xb\pmod{26}$ and $x\equiv a\pmod{26}$.  Conversely, if $b\equiv -xb\pmod{26}$ and $x\equiv a\pmod{26}$, then the encryption function and the decryption functions are equal, since we have
$$
ap+b\equiv xp-xb\equiv x(p-b)\pmod{26},$$
so the encryption function equals the decyrption function, because the function that sends the input $p$ to $ap+b\bmod 26$ (the encryption function) gives the same value as sending it to $x(c-b)\pmod{26}$ (the decryption function).

So we are trying to find number pairs $(a,b)$ such that for $x$ the multiplicative inverse of $a$ modulo $26$, we have $xb\equiv -b$ and $x\equiv a$ modulo $26$. This is how we got those two congruences. Not merely from $xc-xb\bmod 26$, but from this having to be the same as $ac+b\bmod{26}$ for all values of $c$.

At this point we have that we need an $a$ that is its own multiplicative inverse modulo $26$. The only two such values are $1\bmod 26$ and $25\bmod 26$ (the only values modulo $13$, a prime, are $1$ and $-1$; the only value modulo $2$ is $1$; so by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, the only values modulo $26$ are indeed $1$ and $-1$).

If $a=1$, then $x=1$ and the second congruence becomes $b\equiv -b\pmod{26}$. The only solution is $b=13\bmod 26$. So one pair is $(1,13)$.

If $a=-1$ then $x-=1$ and the second congruence becomes $b\equiv b\pmod{26}$. Any value of $b$ will work, so here we get all pairs of the form $(-1,b)$, $b=0,1,\ldots,25$; this is the solution given.

Comment: How were you able to switch $ap+b$ for $ac+b$ when setting the two functions congruent mod 26?

Comment: @mehsheeman: It's function. The function takes input $p$ and yields out put $ap+b$. If you apply it to the input $c$, you get $ac+b$. We are saying that the decryption function and the encryption function are equal, so if you apply them both to the argument $c$ you get the same output.

Comment: I see. So that’s why you prove the converse $ap+b≡xp−xb≡x(p−b)(mod26)$. You want to show that when you input $p$ into $ap+b$, you get the same result as $x(p-b)$?

Comment: @mehsheenman What converse? I assume that $(a,b)$ is a pair for which the encryption and decryption functions are equal. That means that for every $c$, we have $ac+b\equiv x(c-b)\pmod{26}$. We proceed from there to obtain *necessary*  conditions for $(a,b)$  to be such a pair. Then we show that the necessary conditions are in fact also sufficient. There is no "converse" because you are not asked to prove an if and only if, you are asked to find all pairs that work. PS use `\pmod{26}` to get the space, parentheses, and `mod`  in roman typeface; use `\bmod 26` to get the binary operator mod.

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect formatting. I was referring to when you said “then the encryption function and the decryption functions are equal, since we have
$ap+b≡xp−xb≡x(p−b)\pmod{26}$”. Here, you replaced $c$ with $p$, so I assumed you were trying to prove that the function holds for an input $p$ as well.

Comment: Also, how did you know that you needed to find an $a$ that is its own inverse?

Comment: @mehsheenman I explain *all of that* in the post and the comment. $p$ and $c$ are just the names of the input. You can call them whatever you want that is not in use. I plugged on **the same input** to the encryption and decryption functions because I am supposed to get the same output from both. And I know I need to find $a$ that is its own inverse because I found that I need $ap$ to be thevsame as $xp$ **for all $p$**, so I need $a=x$ (put $p=1$). **I said so explicitly**.